# Add a special product to Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, subscription

I'm new to Dynamics CRM 2016 and I'm about specifying my products.

The problem is: I can't find the right way to do that.

I have two types of products:

1. "Product x" to rent or to sell. So I need to specify for each "Product x" two prices (price for renting and price for selling), but I can't find a way to specify that. Any good practices to cover this need?
   Also, if "product x" is rented, which entity should I use to track that "sale"? order entity? contract entity?
2. "Product y" which is never sold alone but packaged with other "products y" in bundles. Bundles are sold as subscription plans such as STANDARD plan (contains 3 "product y"'s) and PREMIUM plan (contains 10 "product y"'s). Subscriptions can be monthly, quarterly, bi-yearly and yearly.
   Based on Dynamics entities, I can guess that STANDARD plan and PREMIUM plan could be bundles, but how can user sells these bundles based on subscription duration. Should I:

   - create bundles of bundles: create "bundle standard 1" which is
     equivalent to 1 month of a standard subscription, "bundle standard 3" which is equivalent to 3 months of a standard subscription... or
   - add quantity to bundle order (quarterly standard subscription will be equivalent to an order with 3 standard bundles). If this is the recommended solution, how can we apply a discount?
   - use contracts and track duration there?

PS:
I already posted this question in dynamics community, but nobody answers: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/256710

Comment: How is this question related to programming? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It is about configuring products into Dynamics CRM. I did some research and I can find many questions about configuration and not only programming. Anyway, do you have any idea where can I post this question?

Comment: I'd say one bundle per type per rent period should accomplish this, but there's a million ways to design this...

Comment: @Alex, thank you. I have another question: do you have any idea if a contract can be helpful in this case? For example, if a customer buys a plan (represented by a bundle) for 9 months and his rent period is every 3 months, So we can create a contract with frequency. What do you think?

Comment: Contracts are meant exactly for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

You are asking us to design your project. This is too broad and off-topic in SO.

This is what I will do. CRM allows you to customize the system how we want. So play around.

Do a POC (proof of concept) for your understanding of how crm works. [Set up a product catalog: Walkthrough](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/set-up-a-product-catalog-walkthrough.aspx)

You have to design
[Product catalog & Pricelist](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/misscrm360exploration/archive/2015/01/13/pricing-method-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-product-catalog-all-in-1-explanation) with your system in mind.

Your question sounds like you are a functional consultant, But SO is Developer Q&A site. Still CRM techno-functional guys will help you to overcome certain design questions. But it’s a thin line.